# Tbcd support in OSS Nokalva

Tags: java, asn.1

As I can see, OSS Nokalva Java api have support for BCD coding (ByteTool class have methods toBCD and parseBCD), but doesn't have for TBCD. Does anyone know how to deal with it?
Or does anyone know how to implement in Java conversion from String into TBCD encoded byte array and vice versa?
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OSS Nokalva has a question and answer in their Knowledge Base regarding TBCD. Please look at http://www.oss.com/asn1/knowledge-center/asn1-java/209.html for an example you can download for handling TBCD.

Please note that the earlier answer here has incorrect code which relies on existing ByteTool BCD methods that do not work with TBCD in the general case.  That code handles TBCD as BCD with nibbles swapped.  The ByteTool BCD code will throw NumberFormatException for valid TBCD when it is not valid BCD.  See the URL above for code that properly handles TBCD.

Paul

Comment: Thanks Paul.I was searching on OSS Nokalva site for TBCD, but I didn't found that in Knowledge Base.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer to myself. In order to implement TBCD encoding and decoding of decimal number given in String format I made the following methods:

This method reverse upper and lower 4 bits of byte.

```
private byte reverseByte(byte bInput){
   return (byte) ((byte)((bInput & (byte)0x0f)<<4) + (byte)((bInput &(byte)0xf0)>>>4)&0x0f));
}
```

Method that accept input decimal String and return TBCD encoded byte array. This method use a method parseBCD from ByteTool class of OSS Nokalva java api.

```
public static byte[] parseTBCD(String input){
byte[] tbcd = ByteTool.parseBCD(input);
for(int i=0; i<tbcd.length; i++) tbcd[i] = reverseByte(tbcd[i]);
return tbcd;
}
```

And the method that accept TBCD byte array and covert it to String decimal.

```
public static String toTBCD(byte[] tbcd){
for(int i=0; i<tbcd.length; i++) tbcd[i] = reverseByte(tbcd[i]);
return ByteTool.toBCD(tbcd);
}
```